# Automatically install app on run from AIDE

Tags: debugging, automation, aide-ide

Is it possible to automatically install an app when testing and running from AIDE? It keeps asking me whether I want to install it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal app cant install an apk in background without root permission.

If your device rooted, It should be asked for root permission before first installing process.

But If you are rooted, still doesnt install automatically, remove data of AIDE (it wont delete your projects) Or check your  root permissioner app for AIDE.